# How to insert JSON Array into an object in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have a following JSON Array :

```
0: {name: "Jan", value: 12}
1: {name: "Mar", value: 14}
2: {name: "Feb", value: 11}
3: {name: "Apr", value: 10}
4: {name: "May", value: 14}
5: {name: "Jun", value: 12}
6: {name: "Jul", value: 10}
7: {name: "Aug", value: 14}
8: {name: "Sep", value: 11}
```

How to insert that response into the data object in the lineData array below? (JSON Data is embedded in a local JSON file). I want to insert the json array respone into the object of the linedata array.

Expected Format :

```
public lineData = [{
    data: [
      { name: 'Jan | 2018', value: 12 },
      { name: 'Jan | 2018', value: 11 },
      { name: 'Jan | 2018', value: 14 },
      { name: 'Jan | 2018', value: 10 },
      { name: 'Jan | 2018', value: 14 },
      { name: 'Jan | 2018', value: 8 }
    ],
    name: 'Component A',
    id: '1'
  }]
```

The relevant files are as follows:

**chart.json**

```
[
    { "name": "Jan", "value": 12 },
    { "name": "Mar", "value": 14 },
    { "name": "Feb", "value": 11 },
    { "name": "Apr", "value": 10 },
    { "name": "May", "value": 14 },
    { "name": "Jun", "value": 12 },
    { "name": "Jul", "value": 10 },
    { "name": "Aug", "value": 14 },
    { "name": "Sep", "value": 11 }
]
```

**chart.ts**

```
export interface IChart {
    name: string;
    value: number;
    //id?: string;
}
```

**chart.service.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { IChart } from '../chart';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ChartDataService {

    private url: string = "assets/data/chartData.json";

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
    
    getChartData(): Observable<IChart[]>  {
        return this.httpClient.get<IChart[]>(this.url);
    }
}
```

**chart.component.ts**

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { ChartDataService } from './../../services/chart-data.service';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IChart } from './../../chart';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-charts',
  templateUrl: './charts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./charts.component.css']
})
export class ChartsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() chartTitle: string;
  @Input() dataSetType: any;
  public chartDataList : IChart[];

  constructor(private chartDataService: ChartDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.chartDataService.getChartData().subscribe( data => {

     //need a solution for here

      }
    ) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first create a `lineData` model

```
export interface lineDataModel {
  data: any[],
  name: string,
  id: string
}
```

in your `chart.component.ts` create lineData array

```
lineData: lineDataModel[] = [];
```

if the return value of your `getChartData()` in your `charDataService` is the same in the one on your first JSON array.

```
this.chartDataService.getChartData().subscribe( data => {
  lineData.data.push(data);
}
```

Comment: I want to insert the first JSON Array(that is the response) into an object in an array like lineData. I put linedata to show that I want an array like that. My chart.component.ts does not have a linedata array. @Stacks Queue

Comment: I appreciate your support, Why such and error? `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'lineDataModel' `. After changing the code as above.